# ParsedContract.sol:1:17: ParserError: Token incompatible with Solidity parser as part of pragma directive

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, ether

Code :
git clone https://github.com/dappuniversity/election
https://github.com/dappuniversity/election/tree/2019_update

Errors faced :

Commands:

Compile:        truffle compile
  Migrate:        truffle migrate
  Test contracts: truffle test
  Run dev server: npm run dev

SANCBHAR-LW7947:election sanchitbhargava$ truffle migrate
Error parsing /Users/sanchitbhargava/Downloads/election/contracts/Election.sol: ParsedContract.sol:1:17: ParserError: Token incompatible with Solidity parser as part of pragma directive.
pragma solidity ˆ0.4.20;
                ^
Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.0.3 (core: 5.0.3)
Node v10.15.0
SANCBHAR-LW7947:election sanchitbhargava$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know `Truffle v5.0.3` uses solidity compiles version `>=0.5.0`. At the start of your contract changing `pragma solidity ˆ0.4.20;` to `pragma solidity ˆ0.5.0;` might solve your issue.

On a side note this might generate other issues. Because `syntax` of `solidity ˆ0.4.20` and `solidity ˆ0.5.0` differ a bit. Mainly how you write the `constructor`. **Example:**

in `solidity ˆ0.4.20`

```
    function <name same as contract>() public {}
```

in `solidity ˆ0.5.0`

```
    constructor() public {}
```